# Change the default template to a custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have created an admin menu bar like "Pages" through

```
register_post_type()
```

and red that the function to switch between custom templates and default templates in the page attributes section is not available within the register_post_type().(picture)

Does anyone know what I need to write in the php file itself, to change the default template to any custom template I want?

[Page Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGhT9.png)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you mean you want the page template functionality in a custom post type?

Comment: Yes but it is not possible according to the 
[Wordpress codex ](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support)

"$supports =  'page-attributes' (template and menu order) (hierarchical must be true) (the page template selector is only available for the page post type)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of WordPress 4.7 you're able to use the page template functionality on custom post types. to do this you need to ammend the template comment as follows.

```
/*
 * Template Name: Leaderhsip
 * Template Post Type: Staff
 */
```

That would give you a default staff template that would use the single-staff.php file or single.php or what ever the normal WP fallback uses. And also give you a custom Template to choose from for in this example, leadership roles.